# Call Javascript callback in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript newbie and has been given a problem to solve so i really need your help.

The problem is this:

I have a loop of companies list. For each company I need to make a ajax call like below. 
My problem is that I want to stay in the loop and just get the value that the ajax call return so I can use that value there. Now I get the return value to the `getData` method. How can I solve this?

```
for (var j = 0; j < companiesToList.length; j = j + 1) {
    getCompanyData(companiesToList[j].id, numberArray, function(data){
      getData(data)
    }
}

var getCompanyData = function(companyid, numbers, callback) {       
    var baseUrl = '../data/financial/company/';
    baseUrl += companyid + '/';
    numbers = numbers.distinct();
    baseUrl += numbers.join(',');
    tiger.ajax.core.getJSON(baseUrl, null, function(data) {                     
        callback(data.financial);
    });
};
```

Comment: did u try `sync` ajax ? just take into account that ur loop might take a while, cause it will continue only when there response is received

Comment: @dav I hope that's not what you meant, but *never* use synchronous AJAX calls. Learn how to handle asynchronous code instead.

Comment: @MaxArt, yeah I wanted to say synchronous(edited), I agree with u, but in rare cases it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this is with promises, using a library like [kriskowal's Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) (or any other interface that implements the promise API):

```
for (var j = 0; j < companiesToList.length; j = j + 1) {
    getCompanyData(companiesToList[j].id, numberArray, function(data){
      getData(data).then(function(result) {
          // do something with result asynchronously
      }
    }
}

var getCompanyData = function(companyid, numbers, callback) {  
    // create a deferred object to return
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var baseUrl = '../data/financial/company/';
    baseUrl += companyid + '/';
    numbers = numbers.distinct();
    baseUrl += numbers.join(',');
    tiger.ajax.core.getJSON(baseUrl, null, function(data) {  
        // resolve the promise with the retrieved data                   
        deferred.resolve(data.financial);
    });

    // return the unresolved promise immediately
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Whether the above will work out of the box for your situation depends on what exactly you need to do inside the loop after the results come back, since if you want to be picky you aren't actually *staying inside the loop*, but using `then` as a callback (if you will) to execute code after the result is retrieved. That being said, the above pattern works well in a lot of situations like this. I can edit my answer if you provide more information about what you need to do with the data.